# checking if a script is running?

Tags: command-line

How can I check if a script (e.g. a bash script) is running (in the background) using command line‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run:

```
    jobs -l
```

Which will show you a list of all backgrounded processes and their PIDs.

Comment: it does not work for me.

Comment: by *background* I mean it has no windows but can be seen a task-manager.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus are you getting any output from `jobs -l`?

Comment: Gotcha. You can search for a running a process by running `ps aux | grep <name_of_script>`. Note `ps aux` lists every running process and grep allows you to search for a specific pattern.